# How can I restructure file names on bulk via batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have 324 files on a Windows 10 machine which are named in the following pattern:

```
[7 Numbers] [Space] [Last name] [Space] [First name]
```

And I need them to be:

```
[Last name] [Space] [First name] [Space] [7 Numbers]
```

I have done some quick research and found that I could write a batch script utilizing the 'rename' function:

```
@echo off
rename “y:\*.txt” “???-Test1.*”
```

However, I was unable to find out how I can program the script to take the first 7 chracters and put them to the end.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt  window, type `for /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to see the usage information for the command you should use. You will be looking to use a `For /F` loop with three distinct tokens and either the default, or a space as the delims. Additionally there are thousands of examples of this type of usage throughout the site pages under the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, please use the search facility at the top of the page to locate them. Please also be aware that your posted code appears to be using smart, _(curly)_, quotes, instead of the correct dumb, _(straight)_, quotes.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be script, and you just want to do it easily, try [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/). Use section (1) Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Given the little detail on the exact formatting of your structures, i.e what happens in the event a surname has a split like `van Halen` which also now contains a space:
anyway, this will cater for the situation as you've mentioned only and not for names/surnames containing spaces.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3*" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt ^| findstr /R "^[1-9]"') do echo ren "%%i %%j %%k" "%%~nk %%~nj %%~ni%%~xk"
```

Note this example will simply `echo` the command and not perform the actual rename. You need to test it first before you do the renaming. Once you are happy with the result printed to console, then remove `echo` from the line.

Note. `findstr` is important here as we need to only perform the action if the file starts with numbers. You can define the `findstr` filter even more if you want to be more specific. Here I just focused on numbers in the beginning of any `.txt` file considering no name or surname should start with a number., Unless you're 50cent or some other random rapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
rem The following setting for the source directoryis a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"

FOR %%b IN ("%sourcedir%\??????? * *.txt") DO FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%u IN ("%%~nb") DO SET /a junk=0&SET /a "junk=1%%u" 2>nul&IF !junk! geq 10000000 IF !junk! leq 19999999 ECHO REN "%%b" "%%v %%u.txt"

GOTO :EOF
```

Please note that this routine uses `delayedexpansion`

The first `for` puts the absolute filename of each file matching the mask into `%%b`

The second partitions the *name* part of the filename (`%%~nb`) into that part before the first space (token 1) to `%%u` and the remainder (token *) to `%%v`

`junk` is then set to 0 and then reset to the value of `1%%u`. `set /a` will leave `junk` unchanged (therefore, 0) if `%%u` is not a numeric string (the `2>nul` suppresses the error message) so if `%%u` is numeric, `junk` will be set to `10000000` ... `19999999`.

Use `!junk!` to access the run-time value of `junk`, check it is within range and if so, `echo` the `ren` required.

Remove the `echo` keyword before the `ren` after checking the resultant report to actually rename the files.